# Sublime to expand selection to beginning of all lines

Tags: sublimetext

Is there any shortcut to expand selection to beginning of all lines? For now, I have to expand selection to end of line for all lines, and use <kbd>→</kbd> to move cursor to beginning of all lines.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + L  does it for the end of line and you can simply move the multiple selected cursor to the beginning.

Works in Sublime Build 3059

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in mind a situation  when you have selected a couple of lines using the "multiple cursors" feature, and the cursors are inside of those lines? You can select everything till the beginning of those lines using `Shift + Home` shortcut.

Comment: `Shift + Home` didn't work for me. I am not sure if I understand your instruction correctly. Is the `Shift + Home` in one of the menu options? Like in `Edit > xxx > xxx`.

Comment: @Stan I'm not sure I understand what you need. Is all you want to just expand selection to the whole line? If so, the shortcut is `Ctrl + L`. If you want to expand selection to the beginning of the line, you use the `Shift + Home` shortcut. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Say my file has 10 lines, I want the cursor to be expanded to the beginning of 10 lines. E.g. if those 10 lines are file path, then I want to type `del` once, and 10 lines are now started with `del`.